# Can we use sentence transformers to embed non english sentences without labels?

Tags: nlp, word-embedding, doc2vec, bert-language-model, sentence-similarity

I was trying to use this project :

https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers

for embedding non english sentences, the language is not a human speaking language, its machine language (x86)

but the problem is i cannot find a simple example where it shows how can i embed sentences using a custom dataset without any labels or similarity values of the sentences.

basically i have an array of sentences lists without any labels for sentences or similarity values for them, and i want to embed them into vectors in a way that it preserves the semantic of the sentence the best way possible, so far i have used word2vec and doc2vec using gensim library so i wanted to try this method to see if its any better?

(also any other suggestion for methods to use is appreciated)

Comment: Plenty of these language models don't require labels/similarity scores, other than internal correlations of tokens in data. (For example, the 'Paragraph Vector' agorithm of Doc2Vec just uses the words that are present in each text.) Of course, machine language is **not** natural language and many of the same useful patterns won't appear. The 'semantics', such as they are, will be both more rigorous in some ways, and more narrow/abstractly-removed-from-recognizable-concepts in others. But some such work has shown some value. So, have you tried it to see whether it works for your intended goals?

Comment: @gojomo so far i have used word2vec with averaging/adding vectors and doc2vec, word2vec worked better but still not so good, was looking for new methods to try out to embed these "sequences", any suggestion?

Comment: For machine code, who knows? It has some similarities to natural-language, but also significant differences, so you have to try it & evaluate how well it works for your specific ultimate purposes. (I haven't seen your specific end-goals mentioned: is this a matter of academic curiosity? Specific commercial application? Other...?) I believe these deeper-network transformers are likely to consider longer-range relationships, and order-of-token effects, better than the simple context-windows of word2vec & doc2vec.

Comment: @gojomo I'm using this for binary clone search, the problem is i dont even know what to try out, i only knew word2vec and doc2vec. I'm basically looking for some new methods to try out to see if they work better or not.

Comment: What does 'binary clone search' mean? What are the prior state-of-the-art approaches? If you try the sentence-transformers in the repository you linked in your question, are the results better or worse on standard evaluations than your previous tests?

Comment: @gojomo basically means turning functions into vectors and searching for the closes vectors in a repository.  the sentence transformers that i linked seems to need labels/similarity for sentences and it seems to be supervised so i haven't used it yet. also the best state of the art i know is asm2vec paper, which basically uses something like doc2vec

Comment: I'm familiar with using summary-vectors for similarity-search, but what's the interest 'binary clones'? What is the state-of-the-art for that purpose? I see that the training-from-scratch section of your linked project (https://www.sbert.net/docs/training/overview.html#creating-networks-from-scratch) mentions similarity labels, but if you have any ability to test these methods for success, don't you have *some* labeled data, at the very least pairs that should be "more similar than average" or "more similar than some other item"?

Comment: (Also, in the domain of machine-code, couldn't you synthesize some similarity-data by running code, even potentially *random* code, on some virtual-machine & considering those fragments that have similar effects on registers or memory-locations to be similar?)

Comment: @gojomo the data is huge so i cant run the code, but i guess you are right and i can for example use the trained doc2vec similarity scores as a label for the sentence transformers methods, just feels weird to use a model to label for another model lol not sure if its common or not

Comment: I'm not sure I'd expect using the `Doc2Vec` scores would help much, as it'd just direct the (new, deeper, more-stateful) model to try to approximate a model you're trying to do better than. But anything is worth trying if you're desperate for training-data & have the time/resources. And really, whatever *other* method you're using to decide whether a model is better or worse is potentially the most-useful training data.